# Delete last character from line that contains specific word

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to delete the last comma from a line that contains a specific string/word

I have tried a couple examples with sed, but none provided the correct result.

```
{
    "src4_addr" : "10.10.10.10", 
    "dst4_addr" : "11.11.11.11",
    "in_bytes" : 70,
},
```

I would like to eliminate the comma from the line that contains the word `in_bytes`.

Expected result:

```
{
    "src4_addr" : "172.27.90.18", 
    "dst4_addr" : "172.27.90.131",
    "in_bytes" : 70
},
```

Comment: To answer the question from the heading of this post `sed '/specific word/s/.$//' file` but perhaps a more generalised solution from the data you added would be `sed 'N;s/,\s*\(\n\s*}\)/\1/;P;D' file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do it:

```
sed '/in_bytes/ s/,$//'
```

Where `/in_bytes/` is a search pattern ensuring only matching lines will execute the following command `s/,$//`, which is a standard substitution to remove a trailing comma.

Example: https://ideone.com/3hEXBY